# Error while Syncing Android studio Project

Tags: android

I'm trying to update an app that is really old and getting a lot of issues; I overcome many of them, now I'm stuck on this.

*Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.*

This is my Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 33
//buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "gps1.com.homegps"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I already changed compile by implementation.
What I'm missing? What I'm doing wrong?

The app doesn't do much, just open an specific web page on the app at full screen and I don't designed it.
I'm thinking in to do it another app by my self, maybe is faster than dealing with an old app that I don't designed.

Comment: Have a look you can get the solution from the link https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1590/how-to-solve-android-error-could-not-find-method-implementation-for-arguments-on-object-of-type-orggradleapiinternalartifactsdsldependenciesdefaultdependencyhandler

Comment: As you are using compile sdk 33,  need to update your gradle version to 4.1.

Comment: @Babul That worked but I also commented a couple of lines about something called MAVEN, I don't know what it was but now is working fine. Thanks!